# Push notifications did not change color in list rows and does not show indicators. what could be the issue?

Tags: notification

Push notifications did not change color in list rows and does not show any indicators in detail page. what could be the issue?

**what i did so far**

1. Created two users in free developer org. One user is system admin, other one is a standard user.
2. I set push notification for case object and for the fields Status and Priority.
3. added Cases from available items to selected items.
4. Used two different browsers firefox and chrome to test how it is working.
5. logged in as two different users in the firefox and chrome.
6. Logged in as system admin, click the case 1027 and open it in detail mode in firefox
7. Logged in  as Sales agent and click the case 1027 and open it in edit mode
8. Change the status field value in Sales agent does not have any impact(i meant the color change) in System admin brwoser.

what could be the issue? can anyone please shed some light on this issue?

Thanks,
Baskaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i caught the issue, i have opened multiple tabs with sales and console apps in the mixture. i have just read a post and now i understood. So push notifications works only if you have one tab with console only opened.